# I want to Print the Abbrevation of the Word but dont know what I am doing wrong

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to Print the Abbreviation of the Word
Write a C program that should take an organization’s name from the user as a string. You have to implement the following function on that string: 
For example: 
Word = Pakistan State Oil 
Abbreviation: PSO
Only Capital Letters from the Word

It is Printing only 1 word.

Code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printAbbrevation(char Word[], char WordAbb[]);
int findLength(char Word[])
{
    int length = 0;

    for (int i = 0; Word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}

void findAbbrevation(char Word[])
{
    int WordLength = findLength(Word);
    char WordAbb[] = {0};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < WordLength; i++)
    {
        if (Word[i] >= 'A' && Word[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            WordAbb[i] = Word[i];
        }
    }
    printAbbrevation(Word, WordAbb);
}

void printAbbrevation(char Word[], char WordAbb[])
{
    int abbword = findLength(WordAbb);
    cout << "Abbrevation of " << Word << " is = ";

    for (int i = 0; i < abbword; i++)
    {
        cout << WordAbb[i];
    }
    
}

int main()
{
    char Word[100] = {0};
    cout << "Enter the Word = ";
    cin.getline(Word,100);
    cout << "Length of Word is = ";
    cout << findLength(Word);
    cout << endl;
    findAbbrevation(Word);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output I am getting :** 
[image: Output]

Comment: A few things. Your WordAbb is not sufficiently long to store the results, therefore you have undefined behaviour. Secondly, you are setting the `i`th character of WordAbb, as opposed to the proper first, second, third, etc. You would need a second index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `findAbbrevation()` function like this:

```
void findAbbrevation(char Word[])
{
    int WordLength = findLength(Word);
    char WordAbb[25] = {0};
    int j = 0;
    
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < WordLength; i++)
    {
        // To continue untill we get a space
        // this marks the start of the new word
        if(flag)
        {
            if(Word[i] == ' ')
            {
                flag = 0;
            }
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Word[i] >= 'A' && Word[i] <= 'Z')
            {
                WordAbb[j++] = Word[i];
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    printAbbrevation(Word, WordAbb);
}
```

Changes I have made are:

- Keep a flag when you find the new word, which is done by checking for spaces in the string.
- For each new word found, add it's first character to the abbreviation string.
- Keep a separate counter for the abbreviation string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `C++` and not `C`, I suggest you use `string` instead of `char[]` as it may be easier to handle sentences and do operations with them this way, particularly if you come from a higher-level language, or if you are new altogether.

If you wanna print the first letter of each word in the string, you can iterate through the string like this:

```
void printFirstLetter(string sentence) { 
    int i; 
  
    for (i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)  
    { 
        //Print the first letter
        if (i == 0) 
            cout<<sentence[i]; 
  
        // Find the space separating the words, then print the next first letter again.
        if (sentence[i] == ' ')  
        { 
            cout<<sentence[i-1]<<" "<<sentence[i+1]; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

By iterating through the string, for example, if you have "George Likes Cats" you will get: `G L C`.

Since you use `C++` and not `C`, you can use `string` instead of chars. This may help fix some issues if you're new to programming.

Comment: I'd recommend taking parameters in by constant reference. You're also printing extra characters, and spaces ...

Comment: Thank you! Feel free to improve on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out by using Modern C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

const std::string findAbbrivation(const std::string& sentance){
  std::istringstream ss(sentance);
  std::string word;
  std::string result;
  while(std::getline(ss, word, ' '))  {
      result += std::toupper(word[0]);
  }
  return result;
}


int main(){
    std::cout << findAbbrivation("Pakistan State Oil") << std::endl;
}
```

The idea is that you split your string by spaces and then convert the first letter toupper and then concatenate it to the result string. You can read about [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) here.